# Which has better performance with map reduce- Hbase or Cassandra?

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra, hbase

I have choice of using Hbase or cassandra. I will be writing map-reduce tasks to process data.
So which will be better choice Hbase or cassandra. And which will be better to use with hive and pig?

Answer (score 1):

I have used both.  I am not sure what @Tariq means by modified without cluster restart as I don't restart the cluster when I modify cassandra schemas.  I have not used Pig and Hive but from what I understand those just sit on map/reduce and I have used the map/reduce cassandra adapter which works great.  We also know people who have used PlayOrm with map/reduce a bit as well and PlayOrm as of yet does not have the hbase provider written.  They have cassandra and mongodb right now so you can write your one client and it works on either database.  Of course for specific features of each nosql store, you can get the driver and talk directly to the nosql store instead of going through playOrm but many features are very similar between nosql stores.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest HBase as it has got native MR support and runs on top of your existing Hadoop cluster seamlessly. Also, simpler schema that can be modified without a cluster restart is a big plus. It also provides easy integration with Pig and Hive as well.